# Differentiate between SVG images and fonts in webpack loader

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm trying to create a Webpack loader, and all other file types are working; however, when it comes SVGs, the loader gets confused and empties the SVG image document via the font loader. Below is the code I am using...

```
  /* Images still being loaded in this test for some reason */
  {
    test   : /\.svg/,
    exclude: '../src/images',
    loader : 'file?prefix=font/'
  },
  {
    test   : /\.svg/,
    include: '../src/images',
    loader : 'file-loader'
  }
```

As you can see, I have tried using `include/exclude` in the tests, however, this hasn't worked.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To fix this, I just used RegEx to exclude any path containing images, like so...

```
 // FONT LOADER
 {
    test   : /\.svg/,
    exclude: [/images/],
    loader : 'file?prefix=font/'
 },
 // OTHER FILES LOADER
 {
    test: /\.(mp4|ogg|svg)$/,
    loader: 'file-loader'
 }
```